# Trying to understand how "linux utility disk" bypasses the LUKS encryption

Tags: dual-boot, encryption, luks, encfs

So I was reading about the [encrypted file systems](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EncryptedFilesystems) yesterday and noticed that little asterisk below saying:

> *of note: windows "Linux disk utilities" seem to be able to bypass this encryption entirely.

What does that mean exactly? Does it mean that if you install Windows alongside your Ubuntu system, you are able to access your linux drive without any obstacles using Linux disk utilities software? Or if you connect the hard drive containing your linux OS to external computer with the same software?

Moreover, I'm interested to hear if this also applies to **encfs** folder encryption and if it can be easily bypassed via remote connection? Thanks for your answers in advance.

Comment: NO. That can't be true. Someone edited that post with wrong information

Answer (score 2):

Please note the flag at the top of that wiki article:

> **Candidate for Deletion**
>
> This article may not be appropriate for this wiki, and may be deleted.

Furthermore the note is incorrect.  I've notified someone higher up as I can't edit this myself.  Seems to be an immutable page.